# Primality of homogeneous ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be the polynomial ring over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $n$ variables.

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ generated by homogeneous polynomials whose coefficients are 1 or -1.

Are there any criterions showing the primality of I ?

I have several examples which I tested using the function is_prime in SAGE but it seems that the software do not produce any answer when the number of variables and the number of generators of I is "big" (more or less 25...).

Comment: The short answer is "no". Unless you know anything about the structure of your ideal there is very little you can say.

Comment: To late to answer, but there is an article that is titled as "Gröbner Bases and Primary Decomposition of Polynomial Ideals", by Patrizia Gianni, Barry Trager, Gail Zacharias printed in Journal of Symbolic Computation, $(1988, 6, 149-167)$ which might be helpful.